# Magento 2: Product stock status is not automatically updated from Out of Stock to In Stock

Tags: admin, stock-status, magento2.3.1

I have facing issue in update admin product stock status `Out of Stock` to `In Stock` in `Magento 2.3.1`

I have updated product quantity 0 and save the product that time automatically updated stock status `In Stock` to `Out of Stock`. But after adding quantity more than 0 and save the product, but stock status can't getting updated `Out of Stock` to `In Stock`.

Any help will appreciate. Thanks.

Comment: check your settings in advance inventory

Comment: Yes I have checked.

Comment: is it set to automatic?

Comment: Yes already checked but not working.

Comment: @KirtiNariya, did you find the solution?

Comment: @Jaisa I didn't find solution yet

Comment: @Jaisa I have fixed the issue. Check my answer.

Comment: @KirtiNariya, I have fixed the issue by simply setting the backorders to No in Configuration

Comment: Disable the backorders and it works fine

Comment: I have already Disabled backorders.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have fixed the issue of product stock status update from Out of Stock to In Stock.

Fixed the issue to override `module-catalog-inventory/Model/Stock/StockItemRepository.php` file.

Follow below steps to create custom module for override `StockItemRepository.php` file and updated code.

> File path: magento/app/code/Vendor/UpdateStockStatus/registration.php

```
<?php
use \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'Vendor_UpdateStockStatus', __DIR__);
```

> File path: magento/app/code/Vendor/UpdateStockStatus/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_UpdateStockStatus" >
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

> File path: magento/app/code/Vendor/UpdateStockStatus/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\StockItemRepository" type="Vendor\UpdateStockStatus\Model\Stock\StockItemRepository"/>
</config>
```

> File path:
>   magento/app/code/Vendor/UpdateStockStatus/Model/Stock/StockItemRepository.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\UpdateStockStatus\Model\Stock;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory;
use Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\Data\StockItemCollectionInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\Data\StockItemInterface;
use Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\Data\StockItemInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockConfigurationInterface;
use Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockItemRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Indexer\Stock\Processor;
use Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\ResourceModel\Stock\Item as StockItemResource;
use Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Spi\StockStateProviderInterface;
use Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\StockRegistryStorage;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Framework\DB\MapperFactory;
use Magento\Framework\DB\QueryBuilderFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\CouldNotDeleteException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\CouldNotSaveException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory;

class StockItemRepository extends \Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\StockItemRepository
{

    public function __construct(
        StockConfigurationInterface $stockConfiguration,
        StockStateProviderInterface $stockStateProvider,
        StockItemResource $resource,
        StockItemInterfaceFactory $stockItemFactory,
        StockItemCollectionInterfaceFactory $stockItemCollectionFactory,
        ProductFactory $productFactory,
        QueryBuilderFactory $queryBuilderFactory,
        MapperFactory $mapperFactory,
        TimezoneInterface $localeDate,
        Processor $indexProcessor,
        DateTime $dateTime,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $stockConfiguration,
            $stockStateProvider,
            $resource,
            $stockItemFactory,
            $stockItemCollectionFactory,
            $productFactory,
            $queryBuilderFactory,
            $mapperFactory,
            $localeDate,
            $indexProcessor,
            $dateTime,
            $productCollectionFactory = null
        );
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function save(\Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\Data\StockItemInterface $stockItem)
    {
        try {
            /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product */
            $product = $this->productCollectionFactory->create()
                ->setFlag('has_stock_status_filter')
                ->addIdFilter($stockItem->getProductId())
                ->addFieldToSelect('type_id')
                ->getFirstItem();

            if (!$product->getId()) {
                return $stockItem;
            }
            $typeId = $product->getTypeId() ?: $product->getTypeInstance()->getTypeId();
            $isQty = $this->stockConfiguration->isQty($typeId);
            if ($isQty) {
                $isInStock = $this->stockStateProvider->verifyStock($stockItem);
                if ($stockItem->getManageStock()) {
                    $isInStockFlag = $isInStock ? true : false;
                    $stockItem->setIsInStock($isInStockFlag)->setStockStatusChangedAutomaticallyFlag(true);
                }
                // if qty is below notify qty, update the low stock date to today date otherwise set null
                $stockItem->setLowStockDate(null);
                if ($this->stockStateProvider->verifyNotification($stockItem)) {
                    $stockItem->setLowStockDate($this->dateTime->gmtDate());
                }
                $stockItem->setStockStatusChangedAuto(0);
                if ($stockItem->hasStockStatusChangedAutomaticallyFlag()) {
                    $stockItem->setStockStatusChangedAuto((int)$stockItem->getStockStatusChangedAutomaticallyFlag());
                }
            } else {
                $stockItem->setQty(0);
            }

            $stockItem->setWebsiteId($stockItem->getWebsiteId());
            $stockItem->setStockId($stockItem->getStockId());

            $this->resource->save($stockItem);
        } catch (\Exception $exception) {
            throw new CouldNotSaveException(__('The stock item was unable to be saved. Please try again.'), $exception);
        }
        return $stockItem;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it working for Magento 2.4.3 version?

Comment: @ChiragPrajapati yes actually this is for magento2.3.1 you can check 2.4.3 version also and let me know if any issue.

Comment: I have tried this on Magento 2.4.3, but its stock status not saving as in-stock while adding quantity.